# go.Bar object from dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

Is it possible to create a go.Bar object with a similar structure to the following code?
What I mean is that I can't find the parameter responsible for "color" as in this case. And I need go.Bar objects to make several graphs on one go.Figure.

```py
fig = px.bar(
        df[df['club_name'] == name_club],
        x='type', 
        y='how_much', 
        color='half', 
        barmode='group'
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `marker` to change the color and precompute each `go.Bar` and combine both bars in one `go.Figure` as follows:

```
half1 = df[df['club_name'] == 'Half 1']
half2 = df[df['club_name'] == 'Half 2']

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=half1['type'],
    y=half1['how_much'],
    name='Half 1',
    marker=dict(color='blue'),  # You can set the color here
)

trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=half2['type'],
    y=half2['how_much'],
    name='Half 2',
    marker=dict(color='green'),  # You can set the color here
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2])
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

fig.show()
```